# TCL: Open file, extract data, copy files and manipulate it afterwards

Tags: file-io, scripting, tcl, text-files

i want to open a text file which has nearly the following content:

```
    $  
    *include_path
    path
    $
    $
    *include
    test.txt
    $
    $
    *include
    test1.txt
    $
    *include
    test1.txt
    $
    *INCLUDE
    test1.txt
    $
```

The script should be able to search for the path which is placed below the pattern "include_path", save it to a variable and copy all text files which are placed below the pattern "include" to a specific folder.

The capitalized "INCLUDE" indicate that the text file is placed in the same directory as the main text file. The lowercased "include" indicate that the text file can be found in the folder with the path below "include_path".

After copying all the text files to the new folder the main text file should be opened and the "include_path" line as well as the following path should be deleted or commented out.

Comment: If you need someone to write a script for you, there's a lot of freelance programming sites.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to put the text inside `<pre>`…`</pre>` tags, so we can see _exactly_ what is going on without markdown reinterpreting it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format! The thing is i'm new to this page and tcl. I  handled the rest pretty well but at this point i need help to conclude my script.

Comment: @Sebastian: Don't worry too much; it's just that when dealing with a transformation script (especially one likely to contain regular expressions) having _exactly_ what is being looked for is ever so useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly tricky format to parse, as it includes lines that are to be ignored and action needs to be taken on multiple lines at once. Here's my first go at parsing it:

```
set f [open "the_file_to_parse.txt"]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    switch -- [string trim $line] {  # Don't know if the space is significant
        "*include_path" {
            set path [file normalize [string trim [gets $f]]]
        }
        "*include" {
            lappend files [file join $path [string trim [gets $f]]]
        }
        "*INCLUDE" {
            lappend files [file normalize [string trim [gets $f]]]
        }
    }
    # No ‘default’ clause, so unrecognized lines are ignored
}
close $f

# Now, show what we've found out
foreach filename $files {
    puts "Will include file at $filename"
}
```

Key tricks in here:

- The `while {[gets …] >= 0} …` is an idiomatic way to loop over the lines of a file. The main alternative — slurping them all in at once, splitting on newline, and iterating with `foreach` — won't work here because you sometimes need to read multiple lines per iteration.
- I've used `file normalize` in quite a few places so we're ending up with absolute paths. However, I'm assuming that the files are all essentially relative to the current directory. If that's not so (e.g., if the files should be relative to the location of the configuration file) we can use other techniques to get it all right. It is, however, a really good idea to use absolute pathnames internally where you can: it avoids all sorts of confusion. (And don't `cd` inside scripts; it confuses things a lot even if it is semantically well-defined.)
- I've not checked if the files exist or allowed the path to have multiple directories on it or any of that sort of stuff. This might or might not matter.
- I've not reported any unrecognized lines at all. In production code, it's usually better to have an explicit comment syntax and then report anything that is otherwise unrecognized. Like that, you don't have problems jumping out where you least expect it!
- I don't bother to check if the lines following one of your keyword lines have data on them; robust code *ought* to check, but it makes things rather longer.
- I've accumulated the files in a Tcl list for convenience (and then slapped some trivial code on the end to print it all out).

<sup>Personally, I prefer to have my configuration files *be* Tcl scripts. Then I can parse them by just using `source`. (Code is data, data is code, and Tcl has the tools to even let that be done safely.) That won't work with the format you've described though.</sup>